# javascript given string of number, DUP, POP, +, -

Tags: javascript

How can I solve this challenge?
I tried to convert string number into number and having struggle to conver DUP and POP

- POP: The machine removes the topmost number from the stack
- DUP: The  machine pushes a duplicate of the topmost number onto the
  stack
- +: The machine pops the topmost elements from the stack, adds them and pushes the sum on to the stack.

-: The machine pops the topmost elements from the stack, subtracts them and pushes the result on to the stack.

```
export class App {
  test: string;
  input: string[];
  result: string[];
  array: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.test = `Word Machine Emulator`;
    this.input = ['23 DUP 4 POP 5 DUP + DUP + -', "5 6 + -"];
    this.result = [];
  }

  ngOnInit(){
   //result should be [23, 3]
  }

}
```

Example 1:“23 DUP 4 POP 5 DUP -"

- 23 => [23]
- DUP => [23, 23]
- 4 => [23, 23, 4]
- POP => [23,23]
- 5 => [23, 23, 5]
- DUP => [23, 23, 5, 5]
- _ =>  [23,23,0]

List item

Comment: so what did you try?

Comment: I tried to convert the string to number, and but don't know how to convert the DUP and POP

Comment: You can try to use switch case. Also please give us more details. I really can't get the process. An example would be wonderful.

Comment: @MuhammedBeraKoç just added example into my question

Comment: @nathan Looking at your example I have written a solution. Remind me if I got it any wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like below. A quick note: `+` is the same as `Number()` when it is applied on `String`.

```js
const solveInput = (inputString) => {
  const tokens = inputString.split(' ')
  let result = []
  for (const token of tokens) {
    if (Number.isNaN(+token)) {
      switch (token) {
        case 'POP':
          result.pop();
          break;
        case 'DUP':
          result.push(result[result.length - 1]);
          break;
        case '+':
          {
            currentValue = result.pop()
            previousValue = result.pop()
            result.push(currentValue + previousValue)
            break;
          }
        case '-':
          {
            currentValue = result.pop()
            previousValue = result.pop()
            result.push(currentValue - previousValue)
            break;
          }
      }
    } else {
      result.push(+token)
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(solveInput('23 DUP 4 POP 5 DUP + DUP + -'))
```

Comment: How can you put the result on the browser?

Comment: Depends on the framework you use. But the pretty forward solution would be to use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Answer (score 0):

C++ Solution with basic test case running. It might help you. We can't use string in switch so I took If else if as alternative.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include<string>

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int solution(string s) {

    vector<string> token;
    stack<int> stack;
    string st = "";

    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
    {  
        if(s[i] == ' ' ) 
        {
            token.push_back(st); 
            st = "";
        }
        else if( i == (s.size()-1)){
            st += s[i];
            token.push_back(st);
        }
        else
        {
            st += s[i];
        }
    }


    //int x=0; int y= 0; int a = 0; int  b = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<token.size(); i++)
    {
    
        if(token[i] == "-")
        {
              int x = (int)stack.top(); stack.pop();
              int y = stack.top(); stack.pop();
              stack.push((x-y));

        }
        else if(token[i] == "+")
        {
            int a = stack.top(); stack.pop();
            int b = stack.top(); stack.pop();
            stack.push((a+b));
        }

        else if(token[i] == "DUP")
        {
            int a = stack.top();
            stack.push(a);

        }
        else if(token[i] == "POP")
        {
            stack.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            int x = stoi(token[i]);
            stack.push(x);
        } 
    }

    return stack.top();
} 

int main()
{
//  string str = "4 5 6 - 7 +";
    string str = "13 DUP 4 POP 5 DUP + DUP + -";
    cout<<"Result is : "<<solution(str);
    return 0;
}
```